# How to calculate coordinate system based on normal vector and center coordinates?

Tags: c++, math, vector, coordinate-systems

I want to calculate the X direction vector that is determined by the normal vector (Z direction vector) and center coordinates.

For example, given Z direction vector Z(2, 5, 8) , center coordinates point P(5, 10, 14)
[image]

Since I have no idea how to do it, any other plain could anybody give me any hint as to what should I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is infinite number of possible X/Y directions.

If you want to get arbitrary vector perpendicular to given Z, you can apply the next approach:

Compare magnitudes of Z vector components.  Exchange the largest and the next components, negate the largest, make the smallest component zero.

For example, if `Abs(Z.z)>=Abs(Z.x)>=Abs(Z.y)`, then vector `X = (-Z.z, 0, Z.y)` is perpendicular (check that scalar product is zero). For your example:

```
Z(2, 5, 8)
X(0, -8, 5)
Y = Z x X (vector product)
```

Comment: Thank you for your support!+1
Exactly, I want to get arbitrary vector X perpendicular to given Z.
I'm thinking..

Comment: If `X = (-Z.z, 0, Z.y)`, is not `X (-8, 0, 5)`?

Comment: In your case you must exchange z and y as largest components

Comment: I apologize. In addition, please tell me if you know the reference document!

Comment: I don't know ref. documents. This is just construction of orthogonal vector using scalar product property.